# Conic Sections - Points on a cone

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

On page 80 of Spivak's Calculus, 4th Edition, he writes:

> One of the simplest subsets of this three-dimensional space is the (infinite) *cone* illustrated in Figure 2; this cone may be produced by rotating a "generating line," of slope $C$ say, around the third axis.
>   ([Here](http://picpaste.com/20130719_074455-Ax3wcaRc.jpg) is a link to the Figure 2)
>
> For any given first two coordinates $x$ and $y$, the point $(x,y,0)$ in the horizontal plane has distance $\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$ from the origin, and thus
>
> (1)  $(x,y,z)$ is on the cone if and only if $z=\pm C \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

I don't understand how (1) follows from the preceding paragraph. Can someone please shed some light on this? Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: If you take a point on the cone and on the $yz$-plane, then $x=0$ and this point should be on the line with slope $C$ or $-C$, since the cone is obtained by rotating the line. This should help you.

Comment: And draw it, and use the Pythagorean theorem.